# Cordova Capture & Camera

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

Is it possible using Cordova camera and capture plugin to initialise the camera on page In say a 400x400 square rather than loading the full screen capture? Reason being I'm after using the front camera on a tablet which when a member of staff clocks in during the process takes a quick photo of the member of staff.

Is this possible with Cordova camera and capture? If so could somebody provide a quick example or point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a great plugin for that: [CordovaCameraPreview](https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview)

Cordova plugin that allows camera interaction from HTML code.
 Show camera preview popup on top of the HTML.

Features:
•Start a camera preview from HTML code.
•Drag the preview box.
•Set camera color effect (Android and iOS).
•Send the preview box to back of the HTML content.
•Set a custom position for the camera preview box.
•`Set a custom size for the preview box.`
•Set a custom alpha for the preview box.
•Maintain HTML interactivity.